Initial input for xref to filter out candidate
I'm working on java project with lsp-mode support, whenever i find references of a class, xref always shows the "import" parts which i never need:

My question is: Is there a way i can prefix (or pre-fill) the xref prompt (find references in lsp-mode) input with "!import " so that i can exclude all the "import" candidates from the references? Or how to filter xref candidates?

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info
